# Is there any currency value that Jackson will serialize incorrectly?

Tags: java, json, floating-point, jackson, precision

Is is well known that numbers like `0.1` cannot be represented exactly in floating point.  If you try to get a string representation of `0.1` though, you will see exactly "0.1" because Java(and many other languages) will do some implicit rounding for you when converting to a string.  What's a bit more surprising is that when serializing 0.1 to a JSON you will still get the exact value even though it is serialized as a number and not a string type.  I'm guessing this is because the entire JSON is basically a string and therefore Jackson just uses the normal string conversion on the double amount.

My question is as follows, is there any currency value(two decimal places or less) 0 < x < 500,000, for which converting from exact value to double, then to JSON or String, produces an incorrect value.

To give some context, I am currently writing something that will take some exact currency values, then pass said values directly to another service in JSON form without doing any calculations on them that may amplify the imprecision.  I will probably use BigDecimal anyways to be safe, but I was wondering if it would be possible to get away with using double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be fine: you can safely [round-trip up to 15 significant figures](http://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-digits-required-for-round-trip-conversions/) from decimal to double and back to decimal, or in currency terms, up to $99 trillion to 1 cent accuracy.